# write a pandas/python function which requires as inputs multiple columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, function, pandas, dataframe, parameter-passing

In a dataframe with two columns I can easily create a third without a function if it is a numerical operation such as multiply df["new"] =df["one"] * df["two"].

However what if I need to pass in more than two parameters to a function and those parameters are columns from a dataframe.

Passing one column at a time is simple using: df.apply(my_func) but if the functions definition is, and requires three columns:

```
def WordLength(col1,col2,col3):
return max(len(col1),len(col2),len(col3))
```

For example, A function WordLength would return the maximum length of the word from any of the three columns passed into it.

I know for example this doesn't work but I imagine something like this to return a result of a function requiring three parameters into a dataframe column:

```
df["word_length"]= df.apply(WordLength, [[param1,param2,param3]])
```

**Update**
Jon, when trying to use your method of passing in three parameters (values from three dataframe columns for a given row I am getting the following error:

```
def get(name,start_date,end_date):
    try:
        df = ...

response = df.apply(get, axis=1, args=('name', 'date', 'today'))
```

Error relating to arguments - I don't understand why it mentions 4 arguments when I have passed in three and the function only requires three arguments...

Error:

> TypeError: ('getprice() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)',
>   u'occurred at index 0')

Comment: Try to add an exemple of input/output to your question to make it easier to address please

Answer (score 3):

I think you need a `lambda` function in your apply:

```
def WordLength(words):
    return max(len(words[0]),len(words[1]),len(words[2]))

df['wordlength'] = df[['col1','col2','col3']].apply(lambda x: WordLength(x),axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    col1            col2        col3                wordlength
0   word1           word10      wordover9000        12
1   anotherword     wooooord    test                11
2   yetanotherword  letter      Ihavenootheridea    16
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you *really* want a function to do this, you can use `DataFrame` operations, eg:

```
df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].applymap(len).max(axis=1)
```

You can use `apply`'s `args` argument to pass in the columns to be processed and make the target function take a variable number of arguments for unpacking, eg:

```
def max_word_length(row, *cols):
    return row[list(cols)].map(len).max()

# Make sure `axis=1` so rows are passed in and we can access columns
df.apply(max_word_length, axis=1, args=('col1', 'col2', 'col3'))
```

Comment: i'd really like to pass multiple columns from a pandas dataframe into a function, and output to one dataframe column yes. that is why I specifically asked the question. The example doesn't matter it's being able to pass multiple columns to the function that matters.

Comment: @yoshiserry okay - gimme a few minutes

Comment: @yoshiserry I think that should cover the base and fairly similar to the syntax you want without overcomplicating it.

Comment: Jon, if you use applymap and you pass in col1, col2, and col3 to a function how do you know which column you pass in ends up as what parameter in the funtion? For example i want to pass three items to a function which creates a url out of them, so the parameters need to be in a specific order for the function to work. However similarly if you had three numbers in a row of a dataframe and wanted to do (item1 + item2) * item3 they would also need to be in a specific order. how do you specify the order?